# General Question about performance of mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, performance, replicaset

I have set up a mongodb replica set on two 100% identical servers (Hardware & Software).

I am running a webcraper with writes to mongodb.
Now i can see that the performance was better as a standalone instance.

As a standalone mongodb the scraping process was running 2,5 hours with max 150 ops.
As a replica set the scraping process is running 6 hours with max 100 ops.

Is this the usual behavior of a replica set ?

See the screenshots from my grafana dashboard.

As standalone:
[image]

As replica set:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the expected behaviour, from the official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb)

> The primary node receives all write operations. A replica set can have only one primary capable of confirming writes ...

Meaning the added nodes just create overhead when talking strictly about performance as Mongo has to sync them up with the primary.

This is expected as the main use of replication is for fail over.

If you're bulk **scraping** and want to speed up performance and don't care about unexpected errors you can change [writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault) replica configuration to `false`.

> With writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault set to false, MongoDB does not wait for w: "majority" writes to be written to the on-disk journal before acknowledging the writes. As such, majority write operations could possibly roll back in the event of a transient loss (e.g. crash and restart) of a majority of nodes in a given replica set.